# How to use kde connect with a android qemu vm

Tags: networking, virtualization, android, qemu, kde-connect

I have an android vm.I use qemu along with virgl for hardware acceleration.I had to build qemu from source for sdl and virgl support.
I used the following build parameters

```
./configure --enable-sdl --enable-opengl --enable-virglrenderer --enable-system --enable-modules --audio-drv-list=pa --target-list=x86_64-softmmu --enable-kvm --enable-gtk --enable-spice
```

My build directory is

```
/home/username/builds/qemu/qemu/build/
```

My VM launch options are

```
./qemu-system-x86_64 -boot c -enable-kvm -smp 1 -name android -device virtio-vga,virgl=on -net nic -net user,hostfwd=tcp::4444-:5555 -cpu host -device ES1370 -m 1028 -display sdl,gl=on -hda /home/username/Documents/android.img -usb -usbdevice tablet -machine q35 -object rng-random,id=rng0,filename=/dev/urandom -device virtio-rng-pci,rng=rng0
```

I would like to connect to my VM and host using kde connect.I assume that requires setting up a bridge and tap ,tun stuff.It would be nice if some one could suggest a easy method to do the above.
My ifconfig output

```
username@username-H81 ~ [1]> ifconfig
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.40  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::7288:16a8:48fe:99e4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:e0:4c:c2:08:55  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 684976  bytes 626450094 (626.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 215101  bytes 23434472 (23.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 83058  bytes 67059421 (67.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 83058  bytes 67059421 (67.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

My host system - Kubuntu 20.10
Guest - android9 from android x86 with kernel 4.9

Answer (score 0):

Found a easy script to set up tap interface.[credits](https://gist.github.com/extremecoders-re/e8fd8a67a515fee0c873dcafc81d811c)

- First find the logical name of your network device In my case enp3s0.(run the command `ifconfig` and `ls -la /sys/class/net/` to find out the logical name ignore the device with the name lo it is a loop back device)
- Then run these remember to replace eth0 with the logical name of your network device name.

```
sudo brctl addbr br0
sudo ip addr flush dev eth0
sudo brctl addif br0 eth0
sudo tunctl -t tap0 -u `whoami`
sudo brctl addif br0 tap0
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
sudo ifconfig tap0 up
sudo ifconfig br0 up
sudo dhclient -v br0
```

- Launch vm with `-netdev tap,id=mynet0,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no -device e1000,netdev=mynet0,mac=52:55:00:d1:55:01`
- To make this changes permanent you have to save these changes to /etc/network/interfaces but i am not sure how.Any help on doing that would be appreciated